# Landsat from Planetary Computer unexpectedly turns up all no data in some regions

Tags: landsat-8, rioxarray, xarray, open-data-cube, stac

Using some code that gathers Landsat 8 collections from Microsoft Planetary Computer into Open Data Cube xarray using a stac search works fine in some regions but in others returns all nan values. This is revealed when trying to clip the collection to a shape, yielding the following error:

*rioxarray.exceptions.NoDataInBounds: No data found in bounds. Data variable: SR_B1*

Here's an example using two polygons, one in North America that works fine and one in South America that errors.  The polygons are the exact same shape, just different locations. I've tested moving it around, and in some regions it works and others it doesn't (mostly seems to work in US locations and frequently not in the rest of the world, but I haven't found a pattern). I set the resolution to be coarse just for faster loading. Note in the print statements that there are numerous (66 and 24, respectively) items in the returned search.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray
import rasterio.features
import odc.stac
import pystac_client
import planetary_computer
from shapely import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd

stac = pystac_client.Client.open(
    "https://planetarycomputer.microsoft.com/api/stac/v1",
    modifier=planetary_computer.sign_inplace)

# Generate two polygons for searching
aoi1 = Polygon([(-84.1629, 42.4763), (-84.1870, 41.5353), (-83.4340, 41.5172),
                (-82.9967, 42.4438), (-84.1629, 42.4763)])

aoi2 = Polygon([(-73.4325, -12.2138), (-73.4566, -13.1548),
                (-72.7036, -13.1728), (-72.2662, -12.2463),
                (-73.4325, -12.2138)])

bbox1 = rasterio.features.bounds(aoi1)
bbox2 = rasterio.features.bounds(aoi2)

# Define the search
search1 = stac.search(
    bbox=bbox1,
    datetime="2017-01-01/2019-01-01",
    collections=['landsat-8-c2-l2'],
    query={"eo:cloud_cover": {"lt": 25}})

search2 = stac.search(
    bbox=bbox2,
    datetime="2017-01-01/2019-01-01",
    collections=['landsat-8-c2-l2'],
    query={"eo:cloud_cover": {"lt": 25}})

# Gather the search
items1 = search1.item_collection()
ds1 = odc.stac.stac_load(items1, resolution=200, chunks={'x': 1024, 'y': 1024})
print(ds1)

items2 = search2.item_collection()
ds2 = odc.stac.stac_load(items2, resolution=200, chunks={'x': 1024, 'y': 1024})
print(ds2)

# Clip the stack to the extent
extent1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=None, geometry=[aoi1], crs='epsg:4326')
extent1.to_crs(ds1.rio.crs, inplace=True)
ds1_clipped = ds1.rio.clip([extent1.geometry[0]], drop=True, invert=False)

extent2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=None, geometry=[aoi2], crs='epsg:4326')
extent2.to_crs(ds2.rio.crs, inplace=True)
# Error
ds2_clipped = ds2.rio.clip([extent2.geometry[0]], drop=True, invert=False)

# Test to see if all the data in the raster is nan
t = ds2['SR_B1'].isel(time=[7])
arr = t.to_numpy()
np.isnan(arr).all()
```

I've swapped out the **landsat-8-cd-l2** collection with the **sentinel-2-l2a** and it works, so I'm not sure if this is Landsat 8 specific issue or something else.